# Gauge Pressure and Bar Pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, inert-gases, gas

I ran into a problem trying to calculate the absolute pressure of an isolated system.
I was given that the gauge pressure in a tire is 200kPa or 2 bars. To get the absolute pressure I would have to add 101.3kPa correct or would I have to add 100kPa because that would be adding 1 bar.

Comment: Well, gauge pressure is relative to ambient. What is your ambient? Some of us live places where normal pressure comes nowhere near sea level. So, I would only add 80-odd kPa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what are you exactly asking! But I guess you are screwing with conversion factors.
 1 bar is 1.01325 atm and inversly 
1 atm is  0.987...bar. So for 1 atm you need to add 0.987bar.